# Twilio iOS sdk - one to one video calls

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to achieve one to one video calls using Twilio video service. I already configure my server side for generating tokens. So, what should I do now? 
Do I need to create room for each user on app start and then join this room with another user? Or it should be some specific room (combination of user1 data + user2 data), if so - when user2 joins this room how should I handle room notifications on user1 side?

Comment: @philnash I guess, you're the only one who can help me with this :)

Answer (score 1):

For one to one user call I would suggest every user might have unique username or anything which is unique ,so you can build up logic for room name like **username1-username2** , and whenever username1 tries to call username2 we can set up logic on backend in a way that will generate token of specific room only.

On receiver end  username2 can receive VoIP or remote notification and this notification user data (payload) should contain room name to be joined so that when username2 receives call or notification, we can make request for joining in same room in which username1 already exist.